# Need assistance with setting node affinity to a helm subchart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to set node affinity to a subchart within a helm chart, and from what I understand I need to use the `--set` parameter to do this, but struggling a bit how to pass that at the cli. This is the equivalent node affinity I'm trying to set:

```
mariadb:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: arch
            operator: In
            values:
            - x86_64
```

Trying to do this, but with the array declarations and such, it feels wrong (and doesn't do anything):
`helm install gitea gitea-charts/gitea -f ./values.yaml  --set 'memcached.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms.matchExpressions.key.arch=x86_64' --set 'mariadb.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms.matchExpressions.key.arch=x86_64'`

Comment: What does the actual template code in the chart look like?  You can't use `helm install --set` or `-f` to override arbitrary parts of the generated YAML; the chart has to specifically support customizing that particular part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for doing something like this, especially when you have a mix of types, is *not* to use `--set` but to use a second values yaml -- or amend the existing values yaml if you have one. Overriding the affinity via set gets quite messy and isn't very readable. But if you use a separate values yaml, then instead of:

```
helm install gitea gitea-charts/gitea -f ./values.yaml  --set 'memcached.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms.matchExpressions.key.arch=x86_64' --set 'mariadb.affinity.nodeAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.nodeSelectorTerms.matchExpressions.key.arch=x86_64'
```

You would just have

```
helm install gitea gitea-charts/gitea -f ./values.yaml
```

(if you amended the existing values.yaml)

or

```
helm install gitea gitea-charts/gitea -f ./values.yaml -f ./affinity.yaml
```

(if you chose to put the affinity in a separate yaml.)

EDIT (Information provided by Emily):  Output of getting the mariadb pod:

```
NAME              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
gitea-mariadb-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (55s ago)   3m59s
```

(Pod is failing as the bitnami chart doesn't support arm and this is an arm host)

It's affinity in the pod:

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
              app.kubernetes.io/instance: gitea
              app.kubernetes.io/name: mariadb
          namespaces:
          - default
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        weight: 1
```

Contents of affinity.yaml

```
mariadb:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: arch
            operator: In
            values:
            - x86_64
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I must be missing something for sure. I tried adding the above node affinity block to an `affinity.yaml` and it doesn't respect it. I also got a hold of the `values.yaml` for the subcharts, tried specifying it there and adding it to the helm call with `-f mariadbvalues.yaml` , and it doesn't seem to reflect it either. Thanks!

Comment: When you say "it doesn't do anything" in your OP, what do you mean? Does it schedule on nodes which are not x86_64?. Also, you can see whether your mariadb and Memcached pods did take your affinity settings by `kubectl edit`ing the pods themsels and looking for the affinity block you configured.

Comment: Apologies; it wasn't following the affinity I set and was going to nodes without the label. Let me take a look at the pods and see what they are saying when I edit them

Comment: Looks like it varies by the pod, what's interesting is memcached seems to respect the node affinity when added, but mariadb does not. It's actually set to following the primary component of the gitea instance.

Comment: Can you please add the output from `kubectl get pod -n {namespace} {name-of-a-mariadb-pod}` where the affinity isn't working? (you can edit the question for this update)

Comment: Additionally, if the chart is not confidential, are you able to share it so others can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I updated the description above (waiting for approval by a reviewer), and the chart is from https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-on-kubernetes/

Only issue I am having is the bitnami charts don't support arm64, so when it deploys mariadb, it's sometimes going to an arm node instead of the ones labeled x86_64

Comment: I may have figured it out, doing more testing. In the mariadb chart, the affinity is per primary and secondary nodes. I needed to add it under `primary:`

Comment: Excellent. Let us know if that does fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Blender Fox for the help and digging. The issue was that while the memcached chart nested `affinity:` under the main config, the databases (postgresql and mariadb) had additional settings for the primary and any secondary nodes. I fixed it by doing the following within the main gitea chart under the setting overrides for the `mariadb` subchart:

```
<...snip...>
primary:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
         - matchExpressions:
           - key: arch
            operator: In
            values:
            - x86_64
<...snip...>
```

Editing the pod proved to me this was now getting properly set and no additional cli options were needed:
`helm install gitea gitea-charts/gitea -f ./values.yaml`